# Trouble with iOS app force quitting

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm having trouble with my first iPhone app that i'm making (sorry i'm a noob).Everytime I launch the application and click on one tab, I get this error.

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h
#import "AppDelegate.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The line that start at return and ends with class])); is highlighted green and says Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

I have no idea what this means at all, so if you could help it would be great.  Please be as specific as you can be.  I'm using the latest xcode.

Thanks,
Will

Comment: This is a generic error attributed to the `main` function that calls all of your other code. There should be a more specific error message given at the top of the output box. Post the message given there to give us more context.

Comment: The two most common cases I see for this are objects getting released too early or an unimplemented selector.  The log will really help, as will performing "Analyze".

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint at the beginning of your method that runs when you hit the "one tab" that causes the error.  Then step through until you come to the line of code that causes the app to fail to the line above.  That previous line of code will contain your offending issue.